# Beamer: How to place the mini frames at the bottom?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, align, mini-frames

I am trying to add mini frames to help with navigation in my beamer presentation, but I would very much like them to be placed at the bottom of slides, and not the top as it's done by `\useoutertheme{miniframes}`.

Is this possible? I'm using the default beamer template by the way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
% optional
\usecolortheme{whale}
% `subsection=false` is optional.
% It suppresse subsection title line in miniframes.
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\makeatletter
% helper
\newcommand\letbeamertemplate[2]{%
  \csletcs{beamer@@tmpl@#1}{beamer@@tmpl@#2}%
}

% Currently template `headline` is `miniframes theme`.
% First, copy `headline` to `footline`.
\letbeamertemplate{footline}{headline}
% Then, reset `headline`
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title} content \end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}{Title} content \end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title} content \end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}{Title} content \end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title} content \end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title} content \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]